# How to enable adaptive tickless kernel mode nohz_full in 16.04 Xenial

Tags: kernel

RHEL 7.0 allows the use of nohz_full together with some other configs to isolate certain CPU cores for intensive work loads and disabled local timer interrupts.

How do I do the same in Ubuntu 16.04? Do I need a special kernel? Or do I just need to pass the options? Do I need to compile my own kernel?

Comment: How do you enable it in RHEL?

Comment: I think you just need to pass "nohz_full=1-15 isolcpus=1-15 selinux=0 audit=0" or similar to the kernel. It is compiled in and fully supported (my understanding).

Comment: Oh, and CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL (rather than CONFIG_NO_HZ or CONFIG_HZ)

Comment: Keep an eye on this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1587265

Comment: There is no real response to the issue there at all... (yet anyway)

Comment: But I think judging by what I found in the kernel config in /boot, it looks like I need to compile it in myself (at least for the generic kernel). Not sure if there are more appropriate ones that already include it.

Comment: In this case you really have to compile.

Comment: Yes there is 1 important remark in the bug: it does not work with an Ubuntu kernel; Whatever you set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do. Neither low latency or any other kernel comes with this built in.

To build the kernel follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel and enable CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL